# Rollback transaction with 2 DbContexts in Entity Framework. Use TransactionScope or TransactionBegin?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, dbcontext, transactionscope

I have a 2 `DbContext'`s that I call both of them in one form as you can see here:

```
    dbcontext1.add(object);
    dbcontext1.save();
    dbcontext2.add(object);
    dbcontext2.save();
```

So I have a question: if some problems happen and my record saved by `DbContext1` but not in `DbContext2`, I need to rollback my transaction.

I searched and I found two methods: using `BeginTransaction` and `TransactionScope`. I am confused about which one I should use and what the differences between them are?

I found something like this but i don;'t know how can i roll back this :

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())  
{
  using (EFEntities1 dc = new EFEntities1())
  {
     dc.USERS.Add(user);
     dc.SaveChanges();
  }

  using (EFEntities2 dc = new EFEntities2())
  {
     dc.USERS.Add(user);
     dc.SaveChanges();
  }

  scope.complete();
}
```

Best regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am confused about which one I should use and what the differences
>   between them are?

The difference is that `TransactionScope` behaves like a regular, lightweight and local transaction as long as you use it with a single database connection (SQL Server 2005) or with multiple connections on the same database (SQL Server 2008 and up). If the two or more connections are used within the same transaction scope or more than one databases are accessed (again, depending on SQL Server version), then it is promoted to a distributed transaction (so registered with MSDTC). In your case, it will be promoted.

> I found something like this but i don;'t know how can i roll back this.

As long as you don't call `Complete`, the transaction scope is rolled back as soon as the scope ends (e.g. dispose, the using ends, etc).

If an exception is thrown by either of the db contexts, then in your code `Complete` will not be called and the transaction is going to be rolled back.

From MSDN:

> If no exception occurs within the transaction scope (that is, between
>   the initialization of the TransactionScope object and the calling of
>   its Dispose method), then the transaction in which the scope
>   participates is allowed to proceed. If an exception does occur within
>   the transaction scope, the transaction in which it participates will
>   be rolled back.

This is also the reason why a `Rollback` method does not exist.

You might also want to look into what isolation level to use with it. The default is `Serializable`.

Comment: Thank you dear friend but i thought it doesn't rollback your transaction if the errors happen

Comment: You mean if the error happens in my scope it rollbacks by default

Comment: @EA: For TransactionScopes, yes. It gets automatically rolled back when an exception is thrown (as long as you don't handle it and call Complete anyway). See the update for more and also this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: This is awesome I just kind of found this now... like years too late. I am trying to do using several methods but if one fails everything needs to go back and I was struggling really bad. This looks ace!